# How to pass id of a control in GridView to Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, css, gridview

**SCRIPT**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
   $(".ttip").hide();
   $(".txttwo").keyup(    
    function () {
        var one = $(this).val();
        $(".ttip").fadeIn().text(one);
    });

    $(".txttwo").blur(
     function () {
        var one = $(this).val();
        $(".ttip").hide();
    });
});    
    </script>
```

**CODE:**

```
   <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" EnableModelValidation="True">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                         <p class="ttip bubble" class="bubble"></p>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="abc" class="txttwo tipin" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
```

**FIDDLE**
http://jsfiddle.net/w96LX/7/

Also it would be just great if someone can tell me how can I set the width of bubble such that it expands according to the length of text.
I get tooltip for all the textboxes because I have used class. I need to show tooltip just for the one at a time.

Comment: Where is your grid view?

Answer (score 0):

Just use `$(this).attr("id")` to get the ID of an element. Also, apped `display:inline-block; width: auto;` to make the bubble as big as the content: http://jsfiddle.net/w96LX/26/

Update: 
I did not see an ID in your HTML, just the server side code. You will need to append the ID to a HTML element to receive it. Or you generate inline javascript, that is calling a method to set the ID.

Comment: I know I need to pass Id. But can you by anychance show how am I supposed to do so in the right way?

Comment: There a multiple ways. You could write a new `<div id="grid">` to wrap your view. Then append some data (append this in your server side code) `<div id="grid" data-grid-id="GENERATED-ID">` then, you could just call `$("#grid").data("grid-id");` to get the value of this attribute

Comment: as i think about it.. you may also just use a hidden field... `<input type="hidden" id="grid-id" value="GENERATED-ID" />` and get the value with: `$("#grid-id").val();`

Comment: the bubble expands but it also increases the width of the containing cell of grid.

Comment: then go for the hidden field or append the data to the body ;)

Comment: Please take a look at this http://jsfiddle.net/w96LX/27/

I think it can be solved with css